# How to revapi[ VARIABLE HERE ].revnext();?

Tags: jquery, string, methods

I have this API method :

```
revapi17.revnext();
```

that let me go to the next slide inside the SLIDER number 17.

I have 30+ sliders and I have to do something like this:

```
revapi1.revnext(); 
revapi2.revnext(); 
revapi3.revnext(); 
revapi4.revnext();
```

....

I want to insert a variable instead of the number "17"

This is my code:

```
numberArray = [14,15,16,17,18,5];
jQuery.each(numberArray , function(index, value){
  $(".div"+value).click(function(){
    revapiVALUE.revnext();
  }
}
```

This is what I want to do:

Inside DIV14 do revapi14.revnext();
Inside DIV15 do revapi15.revnext();

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution, simple Google search:

[**How to Call a JavaScript Function From a String Without Using eval**](http://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/)

Relevant part of the article:

```
// function we want to run
var fnstring = "runMe";

// find object
var fn = window[fnstring];

// is object a function?
if (typeof fn === "function") fn();
```

## EDIT

```
var numberArray = [14,15,16,17,18,5];
jQuery.each(numberArray, function(index, value) {
    $('.div' + value).click(function() {
        var fn = window['revapi' + value];
        if (typeof fn === 'object') fn.revnext();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that in your case, instead of checking if the type is `function`, maybe you will be checking if the type is `object`.

Comment: I answered in the main section because it didn't let me insert code in the comments here.